# Given $f$ is continuous and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Prove that if absolute value of $f$ is montone then $f$ is monotone.

Tags: real-analysis

Given $f$ is continuous and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Prove that if absolute value of $f$ is monotone then $f$ is monotone.

I think the absolute value of $f$ is confusing me here.

Any help or input would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: What about $f(x)=(2\cdot\mathbb 1_{\mathbb Q}(x)-1)x$? As required, $|f|$ is continuous and monotone, but $f$ is not.

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be continuous? Otherwise Hagen's function or $f=1-2\cdot 1_\mathbb{Q}$ will work too.

Comment: f is continuous and R->R and absolute value of f is montone.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Split the problem in two cases.

**Case 1:** $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In this case, use the IVT to show that $f(x)$ has always the same sign.

**Case 2:** $f(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0$. If $f(x) =0 $ for all $x$ there is nothing to prove.

If $f(x_1) \neq 0$ for some $x$.

Subcase 2a: $x_0 <x_1$. Let $A := \{ x \in (x_0,x_1)| f(x)=0 \}$. Let $a=\sup(A)$ and prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in (-\infty, a]$ and $|f(x)| >0$ for all $x \in(a, \infty)$. Deduce exactly as in case 1 that $f$ has the same sign on $(a, \infty)$.

Subcase 2b: $x_0 > x_1$. Let $A := \{ x \in (x_0,x_1)| f(x)=0 \}$. Let $a=\inf(A)$ and prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [a, \infty)$ and $|f(x)| >0$ for all $x \in(- \infty,a)$. Deduce exactly as in case 1 that $f$ has the same sign on $(-\infty,a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f(x-\epsilon)f(x+\epsilon)<0$ for some $x$ then $|f(x)|$ will not be monotone. So  $f(x) \geq  0$  or $f(x) \leq  0 $ for all $x$